# Typing doesn't work for Polymorphic component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, polymorphism, react-typescript

I'm trying to create a Polymorphic component, so I could use like that:

```
<Flex as={'a'} href="/about" />

// <a href="/about" />
```

Or even with custom Components:

```
<Flex as={Link} to="/about" />

// <Link to="/about" />
```

But typescript sees only the Props, I identified in interface FlexProps
[image: Types I get]

Here's the code:

```
type Direction = 'column' | 'row';
type Align = 'align-center' | 'align-stretch' | 'align-start' | 'align-end';
type Justify = 'center' | 'around' | 'start' | 'end' | 'between';

type FlexProps<T extends React.ElementType> = {
    as?: T;
    direction?: Direction;
    align?: Align;
    justify?: Justify;
    className?: string;
    children: ReactNode;
    gap?: number;
} & React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<T>

const Flex = <T extends React.ElementType>({
    align = 'align-stretch',
    as,
    className,
    gap,
    direction = 'row',
    justify = 'start',
    children,
    style,
    ...rest
}: FlexProps<T>) => {
    const classNames = ClassNames(className, {}, [
        styles.flex,
        styles[align],
        styles[direction],
        styles[justify],
    ])

    const mergedStyle = {
        gap,
        ...style,
    }

    const Component = as || 'div'
    return (
        <Component {...rest} style={mergedStyle} className={classNames}>
            {children}
        </Component>
    )
}

export default memo(Flex)
```

...............................